# How to simulate negative lookbehind in Go

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to write a regex that can extract a command, here's what I've got so far using a negative lookbehind assertion:

```
\b(?<![@#\/])\w.*
```

So with the input:

```
/msg @nickname #channel foo bar baz
/foo #channel @nickname foo bar baz 
foo bar baz
```

`foo bar baz` is extracted every time. See working example 
https://regex101.com/r/lF9aG7/3

In Go however this doesn't compile http://play.golang.org/p/gkkVZgScS_

It throws:

```
panic: regexp: Compile(`\b(?<![@#\/])\w.*`): error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?<`
```

I did a bit of research and realized negative lookbehinds are not supported in the language to guarantee O(n) time.

How can I rewrite this regex so that it does the same without negative lookbehind?

Comment: How about `(?:^|[^@#/])\b(\w.*)` ?

Comment: Can you give an example which you want as an output?

Comment: What should it do in the case "foo \msg some stuff @name other stuff #chan blah blah"?

Comment: @MayurKoshti the playground link shows the expected output, given various inputs.

Comment: I've updated my reply below to make use of string filtering instead of regex. This'll of course, only work __if__ _you're looking to filter out all words beginning with a character from `[#@/]`_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since in your negated lookbehind, you are only using a simple character set; you can replace it with a negated character-set:

```
\b[^@#/]\w.*
```

If the are allowed at the start of the string, then use the `^` anchor:

```
(?:^|[^@#\/])\b\w.*
```

---

Based on the samples in Go playground link in your question, I think you're looking to filter out all words beginning with a character from `[#@/]`. You can use a `filter` function:

```
func Filter(vs []string, f func(string) bool) []string {
    vsf := make([]string, 0)
    for _, v := range vs {
        if f(v) {
            vsf = append(vsf, v)
        }
    }
    return vsf
}
```

and a `Process` function, which makes use of the filter above:

```
func Process(inp string) string {
    t := strings.Split(inp, " ")
    t = Filter(t, func(x string) bool {
        return strings.Index(x, "#") != 0 &&
            strings.Index(x, "@") != 0 &&
            strings.Index(x, "/") != 0
    })
    return strings.Join(t, " ")
}
```

It can be seen in action on [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/ntJRNxJTxo) at http://play.golang.org/p/ntJRNxJTxo

Comment: But that doesn't do the Right Thing(TM). The lookbehind is used to exclude matches like `/foo` - the regex matches `foo`, ignoring the slash. Fortunately, it can be improved by moving the word boundary anchor one token to the right (after the character class/noncapturing group).

Comment: Looking at the Go playground sample, I think you actually want to capture words which do not start with one of `[#@/]` characters. Is that correct?

Comment: Looks like that's what he's trying to do. At least that's what the regex with lookbehind is doing.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I guess a string-filter is a better way to go in that case. I'll inform the OP about the same as well. =)

Comment: Yes more like capture a sentence that does not start with a word that starts with any of [#@/]

Answer (score 2):

You can actually match the preceding character (or the beginning of line) and use a group to get the desired text in a subexpression.

**Regex**

```
(?:^|[^@#/])\b(\w+)
```

- `(?:^|[^@#/])` Matches either `^` the beginning of line or `[^@#/]` any character except `@#/`
- `\b` A word boundary to assert the beginning of a word
- `(\w+)` Generates a subexpression

  - and matches `\w+` any number of word characters

**Code**

```golang
cmds := []string{
    `/msg @nickname #channel foo bar baz`,
    `#channel @nickname foo bar baz /foo`,
    `foo bar baz @nickname #channel`,
    `foo bar baz#channel`}

regex := regexp.MustCompile(`(?:^|[^@#/])\b(\w+)`)


// Loop all cmds
for _, cmd := range cmds{
    // Find all matches and subexpressions
    matches := regex.FindAllStringSubmatch(cmd, -1)

    fmt.Printf("`%v` \t==>\n", cmd)

    // Loop all matches
    for n, match := range matches {
        // match[1] holds the text matched by the first subexpression (1st set of parentheses)
        fmt.Printf("\t%v. `%v`\n", n, match[1])
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
`/msg @nickname #channel foo bar baz`   ==>
    0. `foo`
    1. `bar`
    2. `baz`
`#channel @nickname foo bar baz /foo`   ==>
    0. `foo`
    1. `bar`
    2. `baz`
`foo bar baz @nickname #channel`    ==>
    0. `foo`
    1. `bar`
    2. `baz`
`foo bar baz#channel`   ==>
    0. `foo`
    1. `bar`
    2. `baz`
```

**Playground**
http://play.golang.org/p/AaX9Cg-7Vx