# Negative lookbehind in go with endline match?

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to match all lines that start with < and subsequent text but I don't want to catch <3. The regex that matches this in JS is ^<(?!3$).*$

```
<3       // doesn't match
<34      // matches
<bla bla // matches
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: [Go regular expressions do not provide negative lookbehind.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33514971/1256452)

Comment: @torek correct and it's a huge pain. Is there some way to simulate it?

Comment: See the other answer—but in general, the best way to handle this is to do your match and then check the match.  Let the regex engine do the hard work quickly, then weed out false positives after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* had to support a complex regex without having to do multiple pass, you can use Go projects like [`skybet/goback`](https://github.com/skybet/goback) which does provide extended regex features (extended compared to the [re2 syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax))

```golang
re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?<=a[0-9]{3,5})a`)
fmt.Println(re.MatchString("a12a"))     // false
fmt.Println(re.MatchString("a12345a"))  // true
```

But, as mentioned in this library:

> The implementation does NOT guarantee linear processing time.